# D3 is attempting to set attributes of SVG as NaN and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to make some basic d3 charts, which I have a little experience doing.  Here is a sample of the JSON I am working with (I have 100 objects, left most out for brevity):

```
var data = [
            {
               "OrderID": 1,
               "ShipCountry": "USA",
               "Freight": 168.0,
               "Version": 2
           },
           {
               "OrderID": 2,
               "ShipCountry": "USA",
               "Freight": 336.0,
               "Version": 2
           },
           {
               "OrderID": 3,
               "ShipCountry": "USA",
               "Freight": 504.0,
               "Version": 2
           }]
```

and here is my d3 code:

```
 var margin = { top: 10, bottom: 30, left: 30, right: 20 };

var width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//svg for chart with margins
var svg = d3.select('#chart-wrapper')
                .append('svg')
                    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

//xScale will be based on orderID attribute
var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 99]).range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([16632, 0]).range(height, 0);




svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return xScale(d.Freight)
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return yScale(d.OrderID);
        })
        .attr('r', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'green');
```

For some reason, the cy property of each circle gets set to NaN- which obviously keeps it from rendering.  I have switched around Freight and OrderID fields, and still only the cy property does not get set correctly.  While debugging, I have logged the values of each, and they appear to be real numbers.  (This also happened while trying to create a line graph- the second number of the 'd' attribute for my path was NaN, which is when I decided to attempt a scatterplot instead)

Any idea what is going on?  Thanks

Comment: If you break on `svg.selectAll()` and call `yScale()` in the console with a number what is shown? Also, you're missing a semicolon after `return xScale(d.Freight)`

Comment: it evaluates to NaN - appears to be a problem with the scale then?

Comment: Seems like it. Does the `.range(height, 0)` parameter need to be an `array` ? `.range([height,0])`

Comment: took the yScale function and made it just the value of d.Freight...throws no error in the console, but also nothing gets rendered at all

Comment: What does `console.log(yScale(d.Freight));` print out as?

Comment: good eye, yes it does.  Fixed that, not rendering at all still though.  Weird.  Anyway, seemed to solve the initial problem, thank you

Comment: No problem. Added it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the argument for `.range()` an array.

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([16632, 0]).range(height, 0);
```

is now

```
var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([16632, 0]).range([height, 0]);
```

Comment: thank you, i would upvote you but my rep is not enough.  sorry for wasting your time haha I stared at that for a long time

Comment: No problem. Happens to the best of us.